# How to snap 2 windows side-by-side(split view) programmatically

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

`NSWorkspace` does not have any support for this. I tried with `Accessibility`, but still couldn't find anything useful.

I was thinking about `AppleScript`, but can't find anything helpful too.

I need exactly this effect [Use two Mac apps side by side in Split View](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204948)

Have you any idea how can I achieve that?

Comment: Here is a GitHub repo for a project that achieves that, check out its code: https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt

Comment: @the4kman Thanks, but I'm looking for something equivalent to [this](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204948)

Comment: @Raymond Hopefully my answer was helpful for you in some way

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a very helpful presentation available [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjVudCclP3WAhWDNSYKHZCMBDEQFgguMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdevstreaming.apple.com%2Fvideos%2Fwwdc%2F2015%2F22160ycymy0qg%2F221%2F221_improving_the_full_screen_window_experience.pdf%3Fdl%3D1&usg=AOvVaw0ObCrbvVSzhUrpATYPMYyk) from `WWDC 2015`. *(The link will download the presentation as a PDF)*

**See the section on Metrics and NSSplitView** - 2nd half (Slide 130 or so)

You'll find some useful code pertaining to the `NSSplitViewItem` class. This will do (I think) what you're looking to do. I looked and wasn't able to find many examples other than these.

It looks like `NSSplitView`uses multiple `NSView` objects to arrange them in "Full Screen Order". The first few slides of the presentation, show how to make an app Fullscreen capable.

**Example :**

```
// Add View
class NSView {
     var subviews: [NSView]
     func addSubview(NSView)
     func addSubview(NSView, positioned: NSWindowOrderingMode, relativeTo: NSView?)
     func removeFromSuperview()
}
// Create SplitView
class NSSplitView {
    var arrangedSubviews: [NSView]
    func addArrangedSubview(NSView)
    func insertArrangedSubview(NSView, atIndex: NSInteger)
    func removeArrangedSubview(NSView)
    var arrangesAllSubviews: Bool
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a suggestion and here's mine, try to determine a value
  x% width, x% height, and verticalalign = (left or right) for each window at the time they are loaded.